# Poisson Approximation When "p" is Large

Tags: statistics

[image]

So we use poisson to approximate binomial distributions when "n" (trials) is large and "p" (probability of success) is small.

What about when "p" is large and "q" (probability of failure) is small?

Would it be 1 - P(k successes)  where we substitube "q" for "p" in the mean above?

Comment: Not exactly. One would probably switch the definitions of Success and Failure, and use Poisson to count 'failures'.

Comment: @BruceET  You mean from p = success and q = failure to p = failure and q = success?

Comment: That's it. In my Answer pretend it's employees in a large corporation having accidents on the job instead of a large number of potential customers going to the shop. Orig'l: Success is a safe day, P(Success) = P(Safe Day) =.998. Modified: P(Accident) = .002. // Not considered in your Q or my A is using normal approx to binom (large n) and Pois (large mean). However, in my A you can imagine a normal curve, maybe N(mean=20, var=20), superimposed on my figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my Comment, you seem to be looking for some intuition about binomial vs. Poisson models. Here is an example that might help.

Suppose you want a probability model for the number of customers at a small shop on a particular day.

**Binomial model.** If there are $n = 10,000$ potential customers and the probability any one of them comes to the shop on any one day (independently of each other) is $p = 0.002,$ Then you could model the number of customers on a day as $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=10,000,\,p = 0.002)$. Notice that $\mu_X = np = 20$ and $\sigma_X^2 = np(1-p) = 19.96,$ numerically, nearly the same as $\mu.$

**Poisson model.** More simply, suppose you have no idea how many potential customers there are, but that past records show an average of 20 customers a day. Then we can
model the number of customers on a day as $Y \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 20).$
In this case, $\mu_Y = \lambda = 20$ and $\sigma_Y^2 = 20,$ numerically, exactly the same as $\mu.$

*Theoretical distinctions:* The Poisson model allows for the possibility that the same person
may patronize the shop more than once in the same day, while the binomial model does not. Also, the Poisson model puts no theoretical limit
on the number of customers in a day, whereas the binomial model does not
envision the possibility of more than $n = 10,000.$ (For practical purposes,
this is not an important distinction because probabilities for huge numbers of
customers are essentially $0$ for the Poisson model.)

*Numerical similarities:* The following brief session in R statistical software shows probabilities of
several numbers of customers in a day according to both models. They are
very nearly the same.

```
n = 10000;  p = .002;  lam = 20;  nr.cust = 15:25
bino = round(dbinom(nr.cust, n, p), 4)
pois = round(dpois(nr.cust, lam), 4)
cbind(nr.cust, bino, pois)
      nr.cust   bino   pois
 [1,]      15 0.0516 0.0516
 [2,]      16 0.0646 0.0646
 [3,]      17 0.0760 0.0760
 [4,]      18 0.0845 0.0844
 [5,]      19 0.0889 0.0888
 [6,]      20 0.0889 0.0888
 [7,]      21 0.0847 0.0846
 [8,]      22 0.0770 0.0769
 [9,]      23 0.0669 0.0669
[10,]      24 0.0558 0.0557
[11,]      25 0.0446 0.0446
```

The figure below shows binomial probabilities as vertical bars, and Poisson
probabilities as open circles. Within the resolution of the plot, the two
models are not distinguishable.

[image]